# Leer XML minuscula y mayuscula C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net

estoy leyendo un archivo XML y pido al usuario que ingrese el nombre de la aerolinea que desea buscar, al dejar el XML con mayuscula la condicion pasa y muestra la informacion que deseo, pero al dejar la informacion en minuscula y en minuscula o mayuscula, no me regresa nada.

```
public class XMLReader
    {
        public XMLReader()
        {
        }
        //Fin de metdo leerXML.
        public void leerXML()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the airline you wish to search: ");
            string name;
            name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                XElement info = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\thoma\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Backup Files\data.xml");

                var airlines = info.XPathSelectElements("aerolinea");
                foreach (XElement el in airlines)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element("nombre").Value) && ((string)el.Element("nombre").Value).IndexOf(name) >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine((string)el.Element("origen").Value);
                        Console.WriteLine((string)el.Element("destino").Value);
                        Console.WriteLine((string)el.Element("fecha").Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XMLReader xmlReader = new XMLReader();
            xmlReader.leerXML();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Aca esta el XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<aerolineas>
    <aerolinea id="01">
        <nombre>VIVA COLOMBIA</nombre>
        <origen>BOG</origen>
        <destino>MDE</destino>
        <fecha>01/03/2019</fecha>
    </aerolinea>
    <aerolinea id="02">
        <nombre>HK Express</nombre>
        <origen>BOG</origen>
        <destino>CTG</destino>
        <fecha>01/06/2019</fecha>
    </aerolinea>
    <aerolinea id="03">
        <nombre>Volotea</nombre>
        <origen>PEI</origen>
        <destino>BOG</destino>
        <fecha>01/09/2019</fecha>
    </aerolinea>
    <aerolinea id="04">
        <nombre>Vueling</nombre>
        <origen>MDE</origen>
        <destino>BOG</destino>
        <fecha>01/12/2019</fecha>
    </aerolinea>
</aerolineas>
```

Comment: A ver si me aclaro... ¿el problema es que un el contenido de un elemento no esté con la capitalización correcta (p.ej. "vUELING") o que sea el elemento el que no tiene la capitalización correcta (p.ej. "nOMBRE")? En el primer caso es comparar Strings ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas y no tiene nada que ver con que el dato venga de XML (y hay montones de ejemplos ya respondidos), en el segundo el XML simplemente es incorrecto y hay que rechazarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo se debe de cambiar

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element("nombre").Value.) && ((string)el.Element("nombre").Value.IndexOf(name) >= 0)
```

Por este

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element("nombre").Value.ToUpper()) && ((string)el.Element("nombre").Value.ToUpper()).IndexOf(name) >= 0)
```

Para que asi pueda entrar a evaluar la condicion teniendo en cuenta que todo es mayuscula.